# How to add values to claims and retrieve it from web api - .Net core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity, claims

I am using Asp .net core 2.1

How to add custom claims after login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to add custom claims after login, you can use the AddClaim method over a new ClaimsIdentity instance

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "some Name"));
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, "abc@xyz.com"));
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);
```

Then to retrieve the claims, you can use the LINQ over the ClaimsPrincipal instance:

```
var identity = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
string email = identity.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Email).Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

Update:
While trying to explore and fix the issue myself, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54532743/adding-custom-claim-not-working-in-asp-net-core-identity) answer which works as an alternate solution to your problem.

Comment: Throw an error:- HttpRequest does not contain a definition for GetOwinContext

Comment: Have you installed the nuget package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin'?

Comment: Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin' causes another error   ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager<TUser>' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager<TUser>  ',  Also issue in 'HttpRequest' doesn't resolved

Comment: The using block should contain

"using System.Net.Http;"